# Autowire session-scoped bean into thread (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, scope, autowired

I have a session-scoped bean in Spring that is set within the web context. I have a task that runs as a Callable, and I need access to this bean from within that thread. How should I accomplish this? If I simply attempt autowiring the bean I get the error message:

> Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread

The session-scoped bean I am injecting looks like this:

```
<bean id="userInfo" class="com.company.web.UserInfoBean" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy />
</bean>
```

And the class I am trying to inject it into looks like this:

```
@Component
@Scope( value = "thread", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS )
public class GenerateExportThread implements Callable<String> {
  ...
  // this class contains an @Autowired UserInfoBean
  @Autowired
  private ISubmissionDao submissionDao;
  ...
}
```

Lastly, the Callable is being started up like this:

```
@Autowired
private GenerateExportThread generateExportThread;

@Autowired
private AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

public void myMethod() {
...
    Future<String> future = taskExecutor.submit( new ThreadScopeCallable<String>( generateExportThread ) );
...
}
```

The ISubmissionDao implementation gets injected correctly, but not its UserInfoBean because that bean is session-scoped. I am okay with doing some manual code work if necessary to copy the object from one session into another at thread startup time (if this makes sense) but I just don't know how to go about doing this. Any tips are appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do manual injection:

Your thread-scoped bean:

```
@Component
@Scope( value = "thread", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS )
public class GenerateExportThread implements Callable<String> {
    ...
    // this class contains an @Autowired UserInfoBean
    private ISubmissionDao submissionDao;

    public void setSubmissionDao(ISubmissionDao submissionDao) {
        this.submissionDao = submissionDao;
    }
    ...
}
```

On your request thread:

```
...
@Autowired  // This should work as a request has an implicit session
private ISubmissionDao submissionDao;

@Autowired  // This should also work: the request thread should have a thread-scoped exportThread
private GenerateExportThread generateExportThread;

...
generateExportThread.setSubmissionDao(submissionDao);
String result = generateExportThread.call(); // Or whatever you use to run this thread
```

Comment: I thought this was working, but it isn't quite. The UserInfoBean object still can't be accessed in submissionDao, when submissionDao is called from within the thread. It gives the error message: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread?

Comment: It looks like also manually setting the UserInfoBean object in submissionDao from outside the thread gets everything working correctly. I'll accept this answer as it gave me everything I needed to solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: You can 'unmanage' submissionDao by using the BeanUtils utility
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html

create a new ISubmissionDao and use BeanUtils.copyProperties to copy the @Autowired bean to a fresh submissiondao