# Accessing a session scoped bean from HttpSessionEventPublisher on session destroyed

Tags: java, spring, session, dependency-injection

I'm working on a Java webapp using Spring framework.
I need to call a webservice when user session ends :

- When the user logs out of the application properly
- When the session expires without user action

I implemented an HttpSessionEventPublisher to call the service via a provided client :

```
public class SessionDestroyedListener extends HttpSessionEventPublisher {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {

        // Retrieve managed beans from SessionEvent
        HttpSession session = event.getSession();
        ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(session.getServletContext());

        // This is the session scoped bean : I can access it from the HttpSessionEventPublisher
        SessionBean sessionBean = (SessionBean) session.getAttribute("scopedTarget.sessionBean");

        // This is the service client : I can access it from the HttpSessionEventPublisher
        ServiceClient serviceClient = (ServiceClient) ctx.getBean("serviceClient");

        // This is the call that raises an error
        serviceClient.callService();

        super.sessionDestroyed(event);
    }
}
```

In the service client (I can't modify it as I want, it's provided by another team), a session scoped bean is injected to retrieve user id for authentication :

```
public class ServiceClientImpl implements ServiceClient {

    // This is the injected session bean
    @Autowired
    private SessionBean sessionBean;

     /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void callService() {
        // The service is called using data from the injected session bean and raises an error
    }

}
```

When the user logs out properly, everything works fine as we are in a request context.
But when the session expires after session timeout, I get the following error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.sessionBean': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:33)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.getTarget(Cglib2AopProxy.java:653)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:604)
    at com.mycompany.myapp.bean.SessionBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$c324aab0.getUserId()
    at com.mycompany.myapp.client.ServiceClientImpl.callService(ServiceClientImpl.java:165)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131)
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.SessionScope.get(SessionScope.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:327)
    ... 18 more
```

**Is there a workaround/hack to call that service with the provided client out of request scope ?**

**EDIT**

Markus explained a similar problem in this question :
[Autowire session-scoped bean into thread (Spring)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184068/autowire-session-scoped-bean-into-thread-spring)

His last comment was :

> It looks like also manually setting the UserInfoBean object in submissionDao from outside the thread gets everything working correctly. I'll accept this answer as it gave me everything I needed to solve the problem. Thanks

For testing purpose I add a setter for SessionBean to the service client :

```
public class ServiceClientImpl implements ServiceClient {

    // This is the injected session bean
    @Autowired
    private SessionBean sessionBean;

     /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void callService() {
        // The service is called using data from the injected session bean and raises an error
    }

     /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void setSessionBean(SessionBean sessionBean) {
        this.sessionBean = sessionBean;
    }

}
```

And called that setter before the method that raised exception :

```
public class SessionDestroyedListener extends HttpSessionEventPublisher {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {

        // Retrieve managed beans from SessionEvent
        HttpSession session = event.getSession();
        ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(session.getServletContext());

        // This is the session scoped bean : I can access it from session attributes
        SessionBean sessionBean = (SessionBean) session.getAttribute("scopedTarget.sessionBean");

        // This is the service client : I can access it from spring context
        ServiceClient serviceClient = (ServiceClient) ctx.getBean("serviceClient");

        // After overriding autowired bean in the service client, no more error
        serviceClient.setSessionBean(sessionBean);
        serviceClient.callService();

        super.sessionDestroyed(event);
    }
}
```

That's not elegant at all but working... The questions are now :

- **As ServiceClient is a singleton bean, does it break the autowire macanism ?**
- **If another user from another session calls a ServiceClient method, will SessionBean be the session scoped bean proxy or the last bean I set in my HttpSessionEventPublisher ??**

Comment: No, it doesn't break autowiring. You are trying to obtain `serviceClient` from application context, and it tries to complete autowiring of that bean rigth inside that method call. You setting sessionBean on it manually doesn't matter, you will never get to that line due to autowiring exception.

Comment: If you use `scopedTarget`, then you will globally set the bean to the service client, and that does mean another session will get reference to it, not the proper proxied session-dependent object. That is assuming `serviceClient` is indeed a global bean and not, for example, prototype-scoped. It you want to actually set a dependency like that, you need to first save previous dependency value and later put it back.

Comment: Main question, though: sessionDestroyed means that session has already ended, whatever it was. And service client is supposed to be used inside a running session, which in your case no longer true. So. Why do you need to do this, and is there no way to work around it?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Thank's for your responses ! Service client uses a session scoped bean. When the user logs out properly (sending a request to logout), il works because we are inside a request context, so the session bean is accessible, even if the session is already destroyed. The problem appears when the session expires because we are out of request context...

Comment: Poking around in Spring sources, it might also look like your code started to depend on internal Spring mechanisms which trigger on session destroy. That is, Spring unregisters the `SessionScope` from your bean factory before your code gets to execute anything. Try ordering your listener (I assume `@Ordered` annotation is supported in there) so it is invoked first, and standard Spring mechanisms invoked after.

Comment: Tried to do `SessionDestroyedListener  implements Ordered` with `getOrder()` returning `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` but I still get the error _Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread_

Comment: Check where session scope is being unregistered in relation to your code. There might be more than one queue for listeners.